# Why do I get typeerror while migrating mysql in django?

Tags: python, django

python 3.8, django 3.1.6

when i input like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': '<db-name>',
        'USER': '<id>',
        'PASSWORD': '<password>',
        'HOST': '<url>',
    }
}
```

the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/CatchUProject/KOLP/klp_project_kolp/KOLP/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/CatchUProject/KOLP/klp_project_kolp/KOLP/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\CatchUProject\KOLP\klp_project_kolp\KOLP\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\CatchUProject\KOLP\klp_project_kolp\KOLP\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\CatchUProject\KOLP\klp_project_kolp\KOLP\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\CatchUProject\KOLP\klp_project_kolp\KOLP\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\CatchUProject\KOLP\klp_project_kolp\KOLP\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\CatchUProject\KOLP\klp_project_kolp\KOLP\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 75, in handle
    self.check(databases=[database])
  File "C:\CatchUProject\KOLP\klp_project_kolp\KOLP\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\CatchUProject\KOLP\klp_project_kolp\KOLP\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\CatchUProject\KOLP\klp_project_kolp\KOLP\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\database.py", line 13, in check_database_backends
    issues.extend(conn.validation.check(**kwargs))
  File "C:\CatchUProject\KOLP\klp_project_kolp\KOLP\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\validation.py", line 9, in check
    issues.extend(self._check_sql_mode(**kwargs))
  File "C:\CatchUProject\KOLP\klp_project_kolp\KOLP\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\validation.py", line 13, in _check_sql_mode
    if not (self.connection.sql_mode & {'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES', 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES'}):
  File "C:\CatchUProject\KOLP\klp_project_kolp\KOLP\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\CatchUProject\KOLP\klp_project_kolp\KOLP\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 379, in sql_mode
    return set(sql_mode[0].split(',') if sql_mode else ())
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

even if I googled, I couldn't find this case

and in a library file 'django\db\backends\mysql\base.py'

there is a method:

```
@cached_property
    def sql_mode(self):
        with self.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute('SELECT @@sql_mode')
            sql_mode = cursor.fetchone()
        return set(sql_mode[0].split(',') if sql_mode else ())
```

I think it's an error because `cursor.fetchall()` returns a byte.

Can you figure out a solution to this problem?

Comment: Please post your code as code blocks, not images. Also.. please include the entire stacktrace, not just the error.

Comment: thx, It’s the first time, so there are many mistakes.
i edited.